# Java - error: <identifier> expected, How to fix it?

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I get this error message saying identifier expected

```
newIntArray3 = addValues(StackA.pop(), StackB.pop());
```

Can someone help me with this please?
I want to add two numbers using stacks character by character and display the answer using a poping a stack.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class sandy {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] newIntArray1 = new int[]{5,9,2};
        int[] newIntArray2 = new int[]{4,7,5,6};

        Stack StackA = new Stack();
        Stack StackB = new Stack();
        Stack StackC = new Stack();

        StackA.push(newIntArray1[0]);
        StackA.push(newIntArray1[1]);
        StackA.push(newIntArray1[2]);
        StackB.push(newIntArray1[0]);
        StackB.push(newIntArray1[1]);
        StackB.push(newIntArray1[2]);
        StackB.push(newIntArray1[3]);

        while (!StackA.empty() && !StackB.empty()) {
            int[] newIntArray3 = new int[4];
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            newIntArray3 = addValues(StackA.pop(), StackB.pop());
            int i=0;    
            while (i<=3);
            StackC.push(newIntArray3);
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println("result: " + StackC.pop() + StackC.pop() + StackC.pop() + StackC.pop());
    }

    public void addValues() {
        int x , y = 0;
        int addValues = 0;
        addValues = x+y;
        System.out.println(addValues);
    }
}
```

Comment: `java!=javascript`

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript` ?

Comment: `while (i<=3);` I see an infinite loop. Please post your code properly.

Comment: You could check why your definition of that value takes 0 arguments but then you are calling it with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This method is not taking any parameter and also return type is missing

```
 public void addValues() {
```

Add this line is using this method, please check

```
 newIntArray3 = addValues(StackA.pop(), StackB.pop());
```

Comment: Even if I change this the problem wont fix

Comment: `newIntArray3<Integer> = addValues(StackA, StackB);`
   
          
`static integer addValues(Stack<Integer> st1, Stack<Integer> st2) `
`addValues = st1.pop() + st2.pop();`